# Effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Tags: terminal, iterm, sudo

I copied a file named class-dump to my `/usr/bin` folder, then neither Terminal.app nor iTerm2 work properly on my MacBook. There is something wrong with the `sudo` command.

Here is what I did based on some online searching:

```
sudo 
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
type sudo
sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo)
ls -@@eil /usr/bin/sudo
1485457 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  168448  7  9  2016 /usr/bin/sudo
md5 /usr/bin/sudo
MD5 (/usr/bin/sudo) = 7d986f7707c0f11264989cd7105ea80d
```

Does anyone know how I can make `sudo` work again?

Comment: Have you run `chmod` on `/usr`, `/usr/bin` or `/usr/bin/sudo` before? The permissions look very wrong - here's what I get from `ls -@@eil`: `101580151 -r-s--x--x  1 root  wheel   360K 14 Sep 01:56 /usr/bin/sudo*`

Comment: Do you have a Recovery Partition on your system? With `sudo` not working you'll need to boot into it to `chmod` the command back into a sane state

Comment: Yes I have run `sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/class-dump` to give class-dump.app more power. As for `ls -@@eil`, I don't know what the result is meant for.

Comment: Does the Recoverry Partition mean using the disk utility? I have tried the emergency function, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

- Boot to Recovery Mode(<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)/Internet Recovery Mode (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>).
- Get the name of your main system volume: `df`
  Usually it's the "Mounted on"- name of the device disk0s2 (e.g Macintosh HD) - simply check the sizes.
- Enter `chmod 4511 /Volumes/Name_Of_Sys_Vol/usr/bin/sudo`

  Replace Name_Of_Sys_Vol by the volume name found in the previous command. If the name contains spaces, escape them with `\`. Example:

  ```
  chmod 4511 /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/sudo
  ```
- Check with `ls -l /Volumes/Name_Of_Sys_Vol/usr/bin/sudo` which should yield:

  ```
  -r-s--x--x  1 root  wheel  168448  7  9  2016 /Volumes/Name_Of_Sys_Vol/usr/bin/sudo
  ```

---

In Sierra with SIP enabled you wouldn't have been able to modify the permissions of sudo to 777. Therefore I assume Sierra isn't installed or SIP is disabled.

If Sierra is installed and SIP is enabled you have to disable it before applying changes to sudo..

Comment: It works! Now the sudo command can work correctly. Thanks!